# Android - MapView TranslationAnimation causes rendering faults

Tags: android, android-mapview, translate-animation

I have an EditText over a MapView. Now When the text was edited I want that the map view goes over the EditText element (via TranslateAnimation). The transaltion of the map view works but it seems that the map view is not designed to be translated because after the translation it is not possible to navigate with the map view without rendering faults.

Anyone had the same problem know a solution or have a workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping all the `MapView` with a view, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/sherlock_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/dumberView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this help you. Hope it helps :]